# Mysql order by value

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have table:

`posts:` **id | author | content**

I need to select all entries from this table with one query, but posts written by author "demo" have to be at the first.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN author = 'demo' THEN posts
END DESC
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8499a8/1)

if you want to order someone else here an other example:

```
 _______________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                               |
|                                                                               |
|      SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY                                              |
|       CASE                                                                    |
|       WHEN author = 'demo' THEN post1                                         |
|       WHEN author = 'sdvg' THEN id                                            |
|       END DESC                                                                |
|                                                                               |
|_______________________________________________________________________________|
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8499a8/11)

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas i added a demo and edited my answer , and other example if you want order more then author = demo

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a UNION and use a predefined value to ORDER BY. 
Select all the posts by demo 1st and then the ones NOT by demo

```
SELECT id, author, content, 1 AS special FROM posts WHERE author='demo'
UNION
SELECT id, author, content, 0 AS special FROM posts WHERE author<>'demo'
ORDER BY special DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want author field as first then you have to write

```
select author, id, content FROM posts ORDER BY author
```

Otherwise

```
select * FROM posts order by author
```